# Standard JavaScript practice for iterating through an entire array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Suppose I want to loop through an entire array to access each element. Is it standard practice amongst JavaScript developers to use a for loop, for...in loop, or for...of loop?

For example:

```
var myArray = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"];
```

For loop

```
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++)
    console.log(myArray[index]);
```

For...in loop

```
for (var index in myArray)
    console.log(myArray[index]);
```

For...of loop

```
for (var element of myArray)
    console.log(element);
```

Comment: what about `forEach`?

Comment: Also, you can do `var i = -1; while(myArray[++i]){
 console.log(myArray[i])
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` should be the way to go, as part of the Array.prototype functions.

> For loop
>
> ```
> for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++)
>     console.log(myArray[index])
> ```

If I had to pick one of the above, vanilla for-loop with length above is the most preferred.

> For...in loop
>
> ```
> for (var index in myArray)
>     console.log(myArray[index]);
> ```

You should avoid this **at all cost!** It's bad practice to mix idioms meant for Object with Array. You may run into buggy iterations through unwanted elements

Answer (score 1):

> For loop

```
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++)
console.log(myArray[index]);
```

This is the best choice for an array, and crossbrowser !
It will permit to break the loop when you want, but not with a `Array.forEach`

> For in

Avoid this approach with array !